# Why do the types change when I move code between files

Tags: f#, inline

I have two files.  The contents of the first file, which is called RailwayCombinator.fs, are:

```
    module RailwayCombinator

    let (|Uncarbonated|Carbonated|) =
        function 
        | Choice1Of2 s -> Uncarbonated s
        | Choice2Of2 f -> Carbonated f

    let uncarbonated x = Choice1Of2 x
    let carbonated x = Choice2Of2 x

    let either successFunc failureFunc twoTrackInput =
        match twoTrackInput with
        | Uncarbonated s -> successFunc s
        | Carbonated f -> failureFunc f
```

And the contents of the second file, which is called Program.fs, are:

```
    open RailwayCombinator

    let carbonate factor label i = 
        if i % factor = 0 then
        carbonated label
        else
        uncarbonated i

    let fizzBuzz = 
        let carbonateAll = 
        carbonate 3 "Fizz" <+> carbonate 5 "Buzz"

        carbonateAll
```

I also have a code block:

```
let (<+>) switch1 switch2 x = 
    match (switch1 x),(switch2 x) with
    | Carbonated s1,Carbonated s2 -> carbonated (s1 + s2)
    | Uncarbonated f1,Carbonated s2  -> carbonated s2
    | Carbonated s1,Uncarbonated f2 -> carbonated s1
    | Uncarbonated f1,Uncarbonated f2 -> uncarbonated f1
```

If I put the code block in the file called Program it compiles just fine.  If instead I put it in RailwayCombinator I get an error at this line.

```
carbonate 3 "Fizz" <+> carbonate 5 "Buzz"
```

The error is:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    string
```

I also noticed that the signature for <+> changed based on what file it is in, but I don't know why the signature changed.  The signature when it is in RailwayCombinator is:

```
val ( <+> ) :
  switch1:('a -> Choice<'b,int>) ->
    switch2:('a -> Choice<'c,int>) -> x:'a -> Choice<'b,int>
```

When it is in Program the signature changed to

```
val ( <+> ) :
  switch1:('a -> Choice<'b,string>) ->
    switch2:('a -> Choice<'c,string>) -> x:'a -> Choice<'b,string>
```

So why is the signature changing?

Comment: At a guess, marking the function inline would fix this, as the default for + is int, but in the second case you use string which forces a change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of your `<+>` combinator uses the `+` operator. The F# compiler does not know how to make this generic (.NET generics do not have a generic constraint saying that the type should be "anything with + operator"). So, the F# compiler picks the first type for `<+>` depending on what is the first piece of code below the definition that uses the operator.

You can solve that by making the definition inline:

```
let inline (<+>) switch1 switch2 x = 
    match (switch1 x),(switch2 x) with
    | Carbonated s1,Carbonated s2 -> carbonated (s1 + s2)
    | Uncarbonated f1,Carbonated s2  -> carbonated s2
    | Carbonated s1,Uncarbonated f2 -> carbonated s1
    | Uncarbonated f1,Uncarbonated f2 -> uncarbonated f1
```

The `inline` are handled directly by the F# compiler and so they support more powerful generic constraints - including a constraint that says "anything with +".